# How to define will_paginate's labels outside of translation files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Installation) in my Rails app.

Since my app comes in a variety of different languages, I don't want to add this to every single one of my translation files:

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: "&#8592;"
    next_label: "&#8594;"
    page_gap: "&hellip;"
```

So instead I created a **custom_pagination.rb** initializer and defined all the labels in there:

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:previous_label] = "&#x2190;"
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:next_label] = "&#x2192;"
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:page_gap] = "&hellip;"
```

This works great for the `previous` and `next` labels. But for the `page_gap` instead of an ellipsis I get an error telling me to create a translation file:

```
<span class="gap">
  <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: de.will_paginate.page_gap">Page Gap</span>
</span>
```

Is there any way to define the symbol for the `page_gap` anywhere outside of translation files?

That would save me a lot of copying in between my translation files.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the missing configuration option: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L23

there is no `page_gap` option in there.

if you have a `default_locale` configured in your application, it's enough to specify that setting for the default like en.yml that would fix the duplication for you.

Comment: OK, this isn't perfect because my plan was to have a bunch of translation files with the same number of total lines in the end. But it fixes my problem, so thank you very much!